# Best way to migrate from NSDictionary to Object

Tags: cocoa, nsdictionary, nscoding

I have an object that conforms to NSCoding (and is archived to disk). One property of this object (myMetrics) is an NSDictionary. In a new version of the software, I need to add a key to this dictionary, but I need to do it before the rest of the app is using the main object as it is a required key.

My thought was to do something like:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
       self.myMetrics = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"myMetrics"];
       ... other properties go here ....
    }

    .... add the new key to myMetrics with default value if it is missing in myMetrics ...

    return (self);
}
```

What I would really like to do is convert myMetrics from a dictionary to it's own class. I am not sure how I would handle this for archived objects that already exist. My thought was:

1. add a new property of class NewMetrics called newMetrics.
2. in initWithCoder if a myMetrics property is found, move its data into a newMetrics property
3. in encodeWithCoder only handle newMetrics and never reencode the old dictionary.

In this way the software uses NewMetrics objects throughout but the initWithCoder is able to handle the old style myMetrics.

Is there any good way to do this while keeping the same property name?

```
@property (atomic, retain) NSDictionary* myMetrics; //  dictionary of parameters

becomes

@property (atomic, retain) NewMetrics* myMetrics; // parameters

rather than

@property (atomic, retain) NewMetrics* newMetrics; // parameters
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You call your new class `NewMetrics` in some places and `MyMetrics` in others. Could you edit your question to use one or the other?

Comment: Sorry about that - it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can convert `myMetrics` from a dictionary to its own class, without renaming the property, while still handling existing archived objects. The new property declaration would be:

```
@property (atomic, retain) NewMetrics* myMetrics; // parameters
```

The `initWithCoder:` function would be something like:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // decode saved NewMetrics object
        self.myMetrics = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"newMyMetrics"];
        if (!self.myMetrics) {
            // fall back to legacy saved metrics NSDictionary
            NSDictionary *legacyMetrics = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"myMetrics"];
            if (legacyMetrics) {
                self.myMetrics = [[NewMetrics alloc] initWithDictionary:legacyMetrics];
            } else {
                // handle having no saved metrics
            }
        }

        ... other properties go here ....
    }

    return self;
}
```

You would have to start encoding the `myMetrics` property under a new key, e.g. `@"myNewMetrics"`, and provide a way to convert the old-style metrics dictionary into an instance of the new NewMetrics class, e.g. `initWithDictionary:` as shown above.

Comment: Would it work to do something like: id tempMetrics = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"myMetrics"]; and then do a test if ([tempMetrics isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) so that I don't need to code it under a new key?

Comment: You could do that, but if an older version of your app tried to decode an archive saved by a newer version it would probably crash. Having the same key refer to two different types of data feels wrong to me. Is there some reason you don't want to use a new key?

Comment: For cleanliness mostly and so the encoding key matches the property key. There are additional reasons why a v2 document can't be opened by a v1 app (and my NSDocument subclass checks for this). Thanks for the suggestions.... helpful indeed.